# mapping one object to another using some functional programming

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to map one array of object into another in a more functional style, I am using typescript.

Basically I am using delete to remove a property on a object, I would like to know if there is a better way to write it.

```
  const data = props.data.map(d => ({
    order: d.position,
    logs: d.batches.map(b => {
      let log= {
        amount: b.scrap,
        batchNumber: '', // NO GOOD
      }
      if (!b.batch || b.batch.length === 0) {
        delete log.batchNumber // NO GOOD
      }
      return log
    }),
  }))
```

example input data:

```
const data = [
    position: 1,
    batches: [
         {batchNumber: '', ammount: 3}
    ]
]
```

result:

```
const data = [{
        order: 1,
        logs:[ {ammount:3}]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input/output data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do another `map` on the batches to return a new array of objects, and attach that to your returned object instead:

```
const out = data.map(({ position: order, batches }) => {
  const logs = batches.map(({ batchNumber, ammount }) => {
    if (batchNumber) return { batchNumber, ammount };
    return { ammount };
  });
  return { order, logs }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9hrgsy3p/4/)**

Comment: I need to add batchNumber if its property exist and its value is different than an empty string, does you code work in this way?

Comment: It does now @Radex.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to make a shallow copy of the target omitting keys you want to delete, for example:

```js
let drop = key => obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, k) =>
    k === key ? r : {...r, [k]: obj[k]}, {});

let test = [
    {foo:11, bar:2, baz: 3},
    {foo:22, bar:2, baz: 3},
    {foo:33, bar:2, baz: 3},
    ];

console.log(test.map(drop('bar')));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another option to the mix: it is possible to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to optionally assign the property:

```js
const data = [{
  position: 1,
  batches: [{batchNumber: '',ammount: 3}, {batchNumber: 'withNr',ammount: 4}]
}];
 
const res = data.map(d => 
  ({
    order: d.position,
    logs : d.batches.map(({ammount, batchNumber}) => Object.assign({ammount}, batchNumber ? {batchNumber} : null ))
  })
);
 
 console.log(res);
```